# PHP how to remove the last part of a filename after underscore

Tags: php, preg-replace, explode

A filename looks like `whatever_test_123234545.gif`.

What is the easiest way to remove the last underscore followed by all characters and numbers after it but not the the dot extension.

In other words i want `whatever_test_123234545.gif` to look like `whatever_test.gif`. A filename can have a random number of underscores. I just want to remove the last part before `.ext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove everything between the last underscore and the `.`. If the filename does't have a `.` or doesn't have an `_` it will not change the filename:

```
$filename = 'whatever_test_123234545.gif';
$new_filename = preg_replace('/_[^_.]*\./', '.', $filename);
```

And to actually rename the file:

```
rename($filename, $new_filename);
```

Comment: This is great. Can you give a little explanation on the preg expression.

Comment: @Pinkie Sure ! The `/`s are just delimeters to start and end the expression, the expression itself is `_[^_.]*\.` Which says find an `_` followed by 0 or more character that are not in the set `[_.]` (so not a dot or an underscore. The `\.` just matches the `.` character at the end. It needs to be escaped with a `\` since `.` has a special meaning in regex. Since we capture the dot we replace the matched string with a dot as well.

Comment: So it basically searches for an underscore followed by as many characters that are neither underscores or dots as it can find followed by a dot, and replaces that whole thing with a dot.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do we need to have `[^_.]` instead of just [^_]

Comment: @Pinkie It won't matter unless the filename has more than one `.`. But in that case you'll probably want to remove it anyways, so a better expression might be `/_[^_]*\./`

Answer (score 3):

The below code will replace the last _XXXXXX before the . where XXX is any number.It will replace only if XXX is a number.

```
$filename = 'whatever_test_56623736373738333.gif';
$new_filename = preg_replace('/_[0-9]+(\.)/', '.', $filename, 1);
```

Comment: OP wants to *remove the last underscore followed by all **characters** and numbers*, not only numbers. (PS. There's already similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630444/7404943) where that requirement is fulfilled  )

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = 'whatever_test_123234545.gif';    
$newstring = substr($x, 0, strrpos($x, '_')).substr($x, strrpos($x, '.'));
```

Comment: This works although but not as efficient as the preg answer above. +1

Answer (score 1):

This one will replace the last _XXXXXX before the . where XXX is any string.

```
<?php 
echo preg_replace('/_[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.)/', '.', 'whatever_test_123234545.gif', 1);
?>
// Prints: whatever_test.gif
```

Comment: Thank but the last part can have both numbers and characters and not just numbers.

Comment: Thanks, But i'm getting $1 for the extension. `whatever_test$1`

Comment: Hmm.
`matt@wraith:~$ echo "<?php echo preg_replace('/_[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\..+)/', '\$1', 'whatever_test_123234545.gif', 1);?>" |php
whatever_test.gif`

Comment: Ehhh, updating it again for you :)